# How to stop "Save Password" alert show？

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I login in, it is long time and I can't do anything before this alert show. How to stop "Save Password" alert show ?

[image]

Comment: the question is I don't want it to show， not  how to close it

Comment: Try this: In xib file select UITextField and change the 'ContentType' to 'Name' in Attritubtes Inspector

Comment: thanks, but the alert  still show